# confidence band around a smoothed function

Tags: r, confidence-interval, smoothing

I am using `earth package`[earth: Multivariate Adaptive Regression Spline Models](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/earth/index.html) regression to get a constant piecewise approximation of my data. I want to plot a band of confidence around it.  Does this make sense to estimate a confidence interval of the smoothed function? If yes how can I do this?

I know that confidence intervals cannot be calculated directly, since it is a non parametric regression but I want to have a coherent result like (plot a band of confidence around my smoothed function) what I can get using `lm` or `loess` smoothing.

**EDIT**

I add some code to clarify my idea, Here what I would do if I am using linear regression or `loess`.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(15)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = c(x + rnorm(15)))
```

#### Using lm

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x,data=dat)
predfit <- predict(mod,se=TRUE,interval="confidence")$fit
```

#### Using loess

```
level=0.95
mod <- loess(y~x,data=dat)
pred <- predict(mod, se = TRUE)
y = pred$fit
    ci <- pred$se.fit * qt(level / 2 + .5, pred$df)
data.frame(ymin = y - ci,
           ymax = y + ci)
```

My question how to get `ymin` and `ymax` if I use `earth` :

```
library(earth)
mod = earth(y~x,data=dat)
```

Comment: please edit your source data.frame "dat". When I try to create it a error occurs: (longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length).Thx

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to estimate a confidence band of the smoothed function. A reference is the [scb](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/locfit/html/scb.html) function for simultaneously confidence band in package `locfit`.

Comment: [Wasserman (2006)](http://books.google.com/books?id=MRFlzQfRg7UC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q&f=false) stated that, "For more complicated methods like trees, **MARS** and projection pursuit regression, I am not aware of rigorous results that lead to valid bands." Maybe we need to wait for the breakthrough in theory.

Comment: @Randel thanks for your interest. I read this also, but I think we can get some practical results using bootstrapping methods...

Comment: I consulted a professor about this, and he told me that it is possible to construct the confidence interval for a fixed point, but impossible to construct the confidence band. But a non-rigorous variant of confidence band, variability band, can be constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth will estimate prediction intervals for you.  Do it like this:

```
mod = earth(y~x,data=dat, ncross=30, nfold=3, varmod.method="lm")
plotmo(mod, pt.col=1, level=.95) # show prediction intervals
```

summary(mod) will print this:

```
varmod: method "lm"    min.sd 0.124    iter.rsq 0.016

stddev of predictions:
            coefficients iter.stderr iter.stderr%
(Intercept)       1.2265      0.2059           17
y                 0.0883      0.1918          217

                          mean   smallest   largest   ratio
95% prediction interval   4.86       3.91       5.1     1.3
```

The above code illustrates the principle,  but a problem with your small sample size is that there is not enough data to estimate prediction intervals reliably.  (We know this because the iter.stderr% are very big, and the iter.rsq is very small.  There is a vignette that comes with the earth package that explains in detail how to get prediction intervals, and some of the potential pitfalls.)